# Javascript - how to check if the parent object is not undefined?

Tags: javascript

I find I'm doing this, whereby I need to check that the preceeding variable is not `undefined` before checking the next one in the chain:

```
if( this.props.someVar && this.props.someVar.data ) {
    // do something with this.props.someVar.data ...
}
```

It would be ideal just to do this:

```
if( this.props.someVar.data ) {
    // This throws an error because I haven't checked if `this.props.someVar` exists beforehand.
}
```

Is there an easier/shorter way to so this, preferably using pure Javascript?

Comment: Check if `someVar` is not undefined using `!= undefined` statement.

Comment: I know, not "pure" JS, but using [immutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/) has the added benefit of having such great API as [getIn](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection/getIn)

Comment: try using `!!` with the parent then test the child

Answer (score -1):

I hate that too. The easiest way is to use `try catch` like this

```
try {
    // do something with this.props.someVar.data
} catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof TypeError) {
       // TypeError happens when an object in the chain is undefined
    }
}
```

Comment: why the downvote?

Comment: This is neither shorter nor easier to understand